# Why unknown host in this case?

Tags: android, http-get

Here's my HTTP Get method to connect to the URL:

```
public void executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/GetMovies.js");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.i("bird",retSrc);
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

And here's how I call it:

```
    try {
        executeHttpGet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("bird","nothing");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/GetMovies.js <-----this url works fine in my browser

But the Exception message is: `UnknownHostException`

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Check This Function

```
 private InputStream retriveInputStream(String url){
    DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest=new HttpGet(url);

    try{

        HttpResponse getResponse=client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode=getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode!=HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
        }
        HttpEntity getResponseEntity=getResponse.getEntity();
        return getResponseEntity.getContent();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Refer This Link For JSON Parse in Android [Click Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

check the permission in you xml existed or not:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: here, i also can successful access the url, try re-build and run, or turn off all network adapter and turn on.

Answer (score 0):

Your AVD might not having internet connectivity.

Close your AVD and reopen it from CMD as `E:\android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator -avd mj -dns-server 8.8.8.8`